# is there a solution to get a sum equal to value of multiple field from elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch data (ingredients list).
I want to get **exactly 4 ingredients randomly** where the sum of **protein** equal to **70**

```
       {
        "_index" : "sample_ingredients",
        "_id" : "C_cH-X8BaYOrJWCswgP-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "main category" : "meat_and_poultry",
          "code" : 24130220,
          "calcium" : 16,
          "vitamin A" : 12,
          "alpha-linolenic acid" : "NULL",
          "vitamin C" : 0.0,
          "vitamin B2 (riboflavin)" : 0.232,
          "linoleic acid" : "NULL",
          "water" : 64.25,
          "carbohydrate" : 0.0,
          "sodium" : 362,
          "protein" : 25.54,
          "name" : "Chicken leg",
          "calorie" : 185,
          "fat" : 9.15,
          "iron" : 1.0,
          "vitamin B1 (thiamin)" : 0.059,
          "category" : "Poultry Products",
          "dietary fiber" : 0.0
        }
      },
      ...
      {
        "_index" : "sample_ingredients",
        "_id" : "DPcH-X8BaYOrJWCswgP-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "main category" : "meat_and_poultry",
          "code" : 24120120,
          "calcium" : 13,
          "vitamin A" : 5,
          "alpha-linolenic acid" : "NULL",
          "vitamin C" : 0.0,
          "vitamin B2 (riboflavin)" : 0.131,
          "linoleic acid" : "NULL",
          "water" : 67.78,
          "carbohydrate" : 0.0,
          "sodium" : 328,
          "protein" : 28.04,
          "name" : "Chicken breast",
          "calorie" : 144,
          "fat" : 3.57,
          "iron" : 0.46,
          "vitamin B1 (thiamin)" : 0.081,
          "category" : "Poultry Products",
          "dietary fiber" : 0.0
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sample_ingredients",
        "_id" : "DfcH-X8BaYOrJWCswgP-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "main category" : "meat_and_poultry",
          "code" : 24160110,
          "calcium" : 33,
          "vitamin A" : 26,
          "alpha-linolenic acid" : "NULL",
          "vitamin C" : 0.0,
          "vitamin B2 (riboflavin)" : 0.161,
          "linoleic acid" : "NULL",
          "water" : 57.23,
          "carbohydrate" : 0.6,
          "sodium" : 579,
          "protein" : 23.42,
          "name" : "Chicken wing",
          "calorie" : 257,
          "fat" : 18.04,
          "iron" : 0.93,
          "vitamin B1 (thiamin)" : 0.078,
          "category" : "Poultry Products",
          "dietary fiber" : 0.0
        }
      },
      ....
```

i.e. i will get exactly 4 ingredients randomly
this is an exemple to what i want:

```
{
  "main category" : "meat_and_poultry",
  ...
  "protein" : 23,
  "name" : "Chicken wing",
},
{
  "main category" : "diary",
  ...
  "protein" : 26,
  "name" : "Milk",
},
{
  "main category" : "meat_and_poultry",
  ...
  "protein" : 16,
  "name" : "beef",
},
{
  "main category" : "fruits",
  ...
  "protein" : 5,
  "name" : "banana",
}
```

**=> sum = 70 protein** 
there is a solution to get a result like that ?there is a solution to get a result like that ?there is a solution to get a result like that ?

Comment: it seems like your question is half ? can you please add more details ? do you want the ingredients where protein  value is 70 or do you want to use multipul field and calulate protein  and if sum is equal to 70 then only return?

Comment: i want to use multiple field, i want to get 4 ingredients where, the sum of the 4 ingredients is equal to 70

Comment: you want to select random ingredients where sum of protein is 70 right ?

Comment: yes like that  .

Comment: As i know you can retrive randomly document using `function_score` query with `random_score` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64330674/5489276) but  not sure if you can do sum as well.

Comment: Agree with Sagar, if you dont have millions of documents random_score could work. According to your context (=number of documents & if you need to make this query often) a second index with all the sums precalculated could be a (faster) solution too

Comment: so can you share a sample query to test it. i can't find any solution alone